# HowTo create an accurate constant-current dummy load using immersion heaters controlled by Arduino?

Tags: arduino, batteries, voltage-regulator, constant-current, dummy-load

Given: variable sized nominal 3.2V LI/LFP battery cells, from little 18650 / 26650 cylindrical A123s up to large prismatics from CALB / Winston etc.

the desire to capacity-test them off grid (no mains power available) as accurately as possible*. Ideally many cells at a time, so with low-cost equipment, namely

- a DIY adjustable constant-current load
- timestamped data-logging of V & A, likely Arduino based
- a LVC set just below the test's stop point to protect the cell from over-discharge
- a shunt-based or Hall effect coulometer for sanity check calibration

This query is really just **about the first item** please. I realize I could use nichrome, or even fencing wire, but I would prefer a safer looking, less fragile and compact self-contained load dump, as this rig will be used in a mobile context, and will need to sometimes travel with me by air.

My idea for variable resistance is OTS immersion water heater elements, inserted via threaded ports into a smallish water tank, possibly if needed with in/outlets to circulate water from a larger one, or perhaps a body of water for infinite heat dissipation, the test may run for up to 20 hours with large enough cells.

The range of power used needs to be variable, from below 10W/3A up to 500W/160A (0.3C or lower discharge rate). I see low power elements at 12V, higher wattages available in 24V 36V and 48V, but I believe the low cell voltage 3-4V will require lots of 12V units?

So far so good? Now the part I really dunno. What sort of (likely Arduino based?) control circuit could precisely vary either the voltage (PWM?) or the resistance? so as to keep the amps pulled from the cell by the heater elements (as accurately as possible, *say 0.5 - 1% using Ah) **at a constant current**?

Comment: 500 watts doesn't necessitate water cooling unless you are not giving the full picture. Using heater elements seems to be making this an XY problem: *If using heater elements then they ought to be water cooled* etc.. And, insisting on using heater elements if you want accurate current control of the battery discharge is a disservice to the person designing it.

Comment: *"Android time-lapse photo app pointed at a voltmeter and ammeter attached to the battery posts" Seems a rather convoluted solution to me. Current and voltage (power) logging by a micro controller has been possible for quit some time. It is very simple and dirt cheap.

Comment: (1) "As accurately as possible" isn't a specification.Use numbers and electrical units. (2) I suspect that using PWM will affect the batteries' response as you will be demanding very high currents in short bursts compared with an unchanging lower current. (3) Why introduce a camera? Why not log the data? (4) Camera on Arduino?

Comment: I was under the impression that dissipating 160A was significant, we aren't talking high voltages here.

Comment: I'm open to other techniques, but a small box that can go through TSA is required, as is safety in close quarters. If only a couple gallons of water will do the job, why not? I'm open to other ideas though, especially in gaining better accuracy at lower cost.

Comment: Accuracy, say 0.5% in Ah measured.

Comment: Yes a data log of voltage and current would be very useful, thanks. Would the same Arduino do that or would each tester require two? Edited post

Comment: "you will be demanding very high currents in short bursts compared with an unchanging lower current" No short burst here, and in most circles 0.3C is considered a very gentle rate. With small batteries (3-5Ah) that is 1-2A. With huge cells to stay below 160A, might need to use up to the 20-hour rate 0.05C. But as I said, constant current, continuously over at least 3hrs, so nothing bursty. Dunno if that still knocks PWM out of the running?

Comment: _"say 0.5 - 1% using Ah) **at a constant current**"_ - why?

Comment: Because Ah is the data I want to collect, I don't want to rely on the accuracy of the coulometer so time spent at CC between 100% and 0% is how you accurately measure battery capacity. Otherwise, please clarify what you are questioning.

Comment: Google feed popped this up https://hackaday.com/2020/02/11/build-your-own-active-load/